# Bash ignoring line-continuing character '\'

Tags: bash

I was attempting to run a program from the terminal, so I wrote the following command:

```
$ for infile in *_1.fastq.gz
> do
>   base=$(basename ${infile} _1.fastq.gz)
>   trimmomatic PE ${infile} ${base}_2.fastq.gz \
>                ${base}_1.trim.fastq.gz ${base}_1un.trim.fastq.gz \
>                ${base}_2.trim.fastq.gz ${base}_2un.trim.fastq.gz \
>                SLIDINGWINDOW:4:20 MINLEN:25 ILLUMINACLIP:NexteraPE-PE.fa:2:40:15 
> done
```

However, this command errored out, the issue seeming to be that bash did not recognize the '\' character. When attempting to rerun the command I noticed that the literal '\;' was used in the command:

```
$ for infile in *_1.fastq.gz; do base=$(basename ${infile} _1.fastq.gz); trimmomatic PE ${infile} ${base}_2.fastq.gz \; ${base}_1.trim.fastq.gz ${base}_1un.trim.fastq.gz ${base}_2.trim.fastq.gz ${base}_2un.trim.fastq.gz \; SLIDINGWINDOW:4:20 MINLEN
:25 ILLUMINACLIP:NexteraPE-PE.fa:2:40:15; done
```

I then rewrote the for loop except fitting the **trimmomatic** command on one line with no '\'. This loop worked:

```
$ for infile in *_1.fastq.gz
> do
>   base=$(basename ${infile} _1.fastq.gz)
>   trimmomatic PE ${infile} ${base}_2.fastq.gz ${base}_1.trim.fastq.gz ${base}_1un.trim.fastq.gz ${base}_2.trim.fastq.gz ${base}_2un.trim.fastq.gz SLIDINGWINDOW:4:20 MINLEN:25 ILLUMINACLIP:NexteraPE-PE.fa:2:40:15 
> done
```

Can someone explain how this happened? Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. What was the original error?

Comment: (1) You're missing a lot of quotes here that are needed for canonically correct code. Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it identifies.

Comment: Make sure you don't type a space after the backslash. It has to be right before the newline.

Comment: (2) The easiest way to have a backslash not behave the way you expect is to have something after it -- a space, a DOS newline instead of a UNIX newline, etc.

Comment: In the second example, where you get a literal `;`, it's because you escaped them, having `\;` in several places that should just be deleted.

Comment: Be sure that what you're providing us with is sufficient to reproduce the problem -- one way to test that is using an online interpreter like https://ideone.com/. See https://ideone.com/kPSIUa as an example that shows your code working fine (with the only modifications being ones intended to make it work without a `trimmomatic` command, and without filenames existing that match your glob -- modifications that are part of building a [mre] anyhow).

Comment: In the first example, you have spaces after two of the line-ending `\`. If those are literally in your command line, that's probably the problem, as @Barmar pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the script by starting with a for loop, pressing enter, typing script, pressing enter and in the end done - the command gets executed. It is basically a one-line for loop for the bash. So to be able to differentiate between the commands that need execution one after the other, bash interpretes each line independantly with different commands to be executed one by one. To separate these commands from eachother, a semicolon is used and automatically added due to the carriage return. Otherwise bash would not be able to know if e.g. "done" is a command to end/execute the for loop of if it isis another system command or even a parameter to a script call. With the ; it is pretty clear. So when you write line 1 - escape it with a leading , it automatically adds a semicolon - which makes it a new line and a new command and your loop crashed. That's why the first version doesn't work and the third one does.

Comment: That's a good point. Does it apply to a specific version of bash? I could not reproduce this on bash 4.4.23.

Comment: That I don't know - but when you type a for loop, one line after the other in a console and finish it with done and execution, you can e.g. hit the up-arrow for repeating the command and that would show you what it has done with it, creating a single line command with the semicolons in it.

Comment: That does not seem like the default behavior. Here is a transcript of a bash session in gnome terminal where `\;` were not inserted.
https://ideone.com/nht9iE

Comment: Interesting - I used it on 'GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)' and it works like that, doesn't seem omnipotential. What bash version are you using?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)`